# How do you include @solana/spl-token in the browser to use Client-Side?

Tags: web3.js

How do you include @solana/spl-token in the browser to use Client-Side? I would like to transfer an NFT with Phantom Wallet but would like to use @solana/spl-token client-side to generate the instruction.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Browserify for both @solana/web3.js and @solana/spl-token to use it on the Client-Side

```
browserify -r @solana/web3.js -s solanaWeb3 -o solanaWeb3.browser.js
browserify -r @solana/spl-token -s splToken -o splToken.browser.js
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the docs and Follow the steps mentioned in the docs. Modify the code as per your requirements.

https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#what-do-i-need-to-get-started-with-spl-tokens

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Answers are expected to contain the relevant code inside them rather than just be a link to the docs.

Answer (score -2):

```
import { getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount, createSetAuthorityInstruction, createTransferInstruction, AuthorityType} from "@solana/spl-token";
```

create from account:

```
 // Get the NFT account of the fromWallet address, and if it does not exist, create it
    const fromAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      fromWallet,
      // pubKey of minted token
      mint,
      // this is owner
      fromWallet.publicKey
    );
```

similarly create to account:

```
const toAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection, 
  toWallet,
  // minted token pubKey
  mint,
  toWallet.publicKey
);
```

create connection and wallets:

```
import {Connection,Keypair} from "@solana/web3.js"

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
const fromWallet=Keypair.generate()
const toWallet=Keypair.generate()
```

create transaction with adding the instruction

```
const transaction = new Transaction()
  .add(createSetAuthorityInstruction(
    mint,
    // current authoirty
    fromWallet.publicKey,
    AuthorityType.MintTokens,
    // this is new authoirty
    null
  ));
```

before sending the transaction, set up the signers

```
const signers = [
  {
    publicKey: fromWallet.publicKey,
    secretKey: walletSecretKeyHere,
  },
];
```

send the transaction

```
import {sendAndConfirmTransaction} from "@solana/web3.js"

const transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  signers
);
```